# Möbius inversion of $1/n$

Tags: number-theory

What is $$\mu * f?$$

How can it be found?

- $f(n) = 1/n$.

Comment: What is a better way to write this question?

Comment: Is your main question "what is a better way to write 'what is the moebius inverse of 1/n?' ?" ? Or are you more concerned with what is the moebius inverse of 1/n?

Comment: Speaking as a non-expert, doesn't $f$ need to be of the form $\sum_{d|n} g(d)$ for this question to make sense?

Comment: @Jim:  $f$ actually is in that form! We can write $$\frac{1}{n}=\sum_{d|n} \frac{1}{d}\sum_{r|d}\mu(r)r.$$  That was partly a joke, but Dirichlet Convolution does makes sense for any two functions on the natural numbers.  Given $f,g$ we just define $$f*g(n)=\sum_{d|n}f(d)g(n/d).$$

Comment: @Eric: I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider $\mu*f$ at the prime powers.  $$\mu*f(p)=\frac{1}{p}-1=\frac{1-p}{p}$$
$$\mu*f(p^\alpha)=\frac{1}{p^\alpha}-\frac{1}{p^{\alpha-1}}=\frac{1-p}{p^\alpha}.$$Then if $n=p_1^{r_1}\cdots p_m^{r_m}$ we have that $$\mu*f(n)=\frac{1}{n}\prod_{p|n} \left(1-p\right).$$ Now, be expanding the product, you can write write $$\frac{1}{n}\prod_{p|n} \left(1-p\right)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{d|n} \mu(d) d.$$  I don't think it can be simplified further.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 3):

$$(\mu * f)(n)=\sum_{d|n} \mu(\frac{n}{d})f(d)=$$
$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{d|n}\mu(\frac{n}{d})\frac{n}{d}=$$
$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{d|n} \mu(d) d$$

When $n=p^k$, then $$(\mu*f)(n) = \frac{1-p}{p^k}$$

So if $n=p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}...p_t^{k_t}$, then:

$$(\mu*f)(n) = \frac{(1-p_1)(1-p_2)...(1-p_t)}{n}$$

Answer (score 2):

Typically, when $f \colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{C}$ is an [arithmetic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function), Möbius inversion is defined as the Dirichlet convolution
\begin{align}
(\mu * f)(n) = \sum_{d \mid n} \mu(d) f(\tfrac{n}{d}).
\end{align}
The arithmetic function $g = \mu * f$ is said to be the Möbius inverse of $f$. For your example,
\begin{align}
(\mu * f)(n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{d \mid n} \mu(d) d.
\end{align}

Comment: You don't really need $f$ to be multiplicative to define the Moebius inversion, nor do you need $f(0)$ defined.  The Dirichlet convultion makes a ring out of the set of functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to a ring $R$, and $\mu$ is just the multiplicative inverse of the constant function $f(n)=1$ in that ring of functions

Comment: @Thomas. Nice Addendum. Thanks.